# searching for unicode characters in marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

How can I search for an encoded unicode character?

e.g. This works correctly

```
search:search('&#x0123;')
```

but this does not:

```
(: $search-for received encoded with &amp; :)
xdmp:log($search-for),   (: prints "#x0123;" :)
search:search($search-for)
```

> Output contains:
>   `<search:qtext>&amp;#x0123;</search:qtext>`

What's the best way to detect if the string contains & and convert it?

Comment: Convert it to what? In XML, ampersands are always entity encoded.

Comment: If I type search:search("&#x0123;") in the module it works. but the variable I receive results in taht qtext snippet

Comment: Any XML output will always encode ampersands. Anything else would be invalid XML. i.e.: `<test>Hello &amp; world</test>/string()` => `Hello world`.

Comment: I think there is some confusion here. If you want a literal `&` in your text, you'd have to escape that to `&amp;`. But `&#x0123;` (ģ) is a real and valid entity itself. No need to escape it..

Answer (score 1):

I think some browser or other tool is fooling you. When I run this in QConsole (MarkLogic 8.0-5.2):

```
xdmp:document-insert('/unicode.xml', <p>hello &#x0123; world</p>)
;
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
  at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

let $search-for := "&#x0123;"
return
  search:search($search-for)
```

I get:

```
<search:response snippet-format="snippet" total="1" start="1" page-length="10" xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <search:result index="1" uri="/unicode.xml" path="fn:doc(&quot;/unicode.xml&quot;)" score="36864" confidence="0.5609438" fitness="0.6934683">
    <search:snippet>
      <search:match path="fn:doc(&quot;/unicode.xml&quot;)/p">hello <search:highlight>ģ</search:highlight> world</search:match>
    </search:snippet>
  </search:result>
  <search:qtext>ģ</search:qtext>
  <search:metrics>
    <search:query-resolution-time>PT0.003526S</search:query-resolution-time>
    <search:snippet-resolution-time>PT0.001206S</search:snippet-resolution-time>
    <search:total-time>PT0.005372S</search:total-time>
  </search:metrics>
</search:response>
```

E.g. the unicode character doesn't get escaped.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks @grtjn for response but, actually, I never ran it in query console! I know this will produce different results.